# Highcharts: Custom dataGrouping approximation: dataGroups cropped by chart area

Tags: javascript, function, highcharts, approximation

See this example custom approximation provided by Highcharts:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/plotoptions/series-datagrouping-approximation

```
dataGrouping: {
    approximation: function () {
        return this.dataGroupInfo.length;
    },
    forced: true
},
```

Scroll the selection from left to right.

Notice that `dataGroupInfo.length` increases and decreases as the `dataGroup` enters and exits the chart area. I believe this is due to the `dataGroup` being cropped by the chart area.

I have attempted to resolve this issue by setting `cropThreshold` to Infinity without success (It seems unrelated).

I need to create a custom approximation that is not cropped by the chart area.

To complicate things a bit, my custom approximation is for `series[0]` and is an average. In my case, it is the result of `series[0]` divided by `series[1]`.

My current attempt is the following:
http://jsfiddle.net/rbwc217s/

```
approximation: function(arr) {
    var numerator = 0,
        denominator = 0;
    if (arr.length !== 0) {
        var start = this.xData.indexOf(this.processedXData[0]) + this.dataGroupInfo.start,
            slicedArr = this.chart.series[1].yData.slice(start, start + (arr.length));
        for (var i in arr) {
            numerator += arr[i];
            denominator += slicedArr[i];
        };
    };
    return denominator !== 0 ? Math.round((numerator / denominator) * 1000) / 1000 : null;
},
```

It works as expected - except on the edge of the chart area. Again, I believe this is due to the `dataGroup` being cropped by the chart area.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I think you simply need to set [`series.getExtremesFromAll`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.getExtremesFromAll), see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rbwc217s/1/ Note: it will scale your yAxis to extremes from all points, as the name says ;) But will group all points at the same time, not only the ones within the visible range.

Comment: @PawełFus Thanks! I didn't realize that this had such an effect on datagrouping. Works like a charm! Now, if there is a way to group the data without affecting the yAxis extremes, it would be a perfect solution. I don't always have much vertical real estate, and given the extremes of my data set, portions of the graph appear to be flat lines at large scale.

Comment: I think that simple plugin like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rbwc217s/2/ should resolve the issue. As you can see, when calculating series' extremes, we can change `getExtremesFromAll` and restore after extremes are set.